# Is that logic to reset the Lists and call Init() over again if there was an exception with the download/s?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

And how can i report to the user that there was a problem and that it's trying over again ? And should i just do it like i'm doing it now reseting everything and calling Init() again or should i use some timer and wait some seconds before trying again ?

In the class i did:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestingDownloads
{
    class ExtractImages
    {
        static WebClient client;
        static string htmltoextract;
        public static List<string> countriescodes = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> countriesnames = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> DatesAndTimes = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> imagesUrls = new List<string>();
        static string firstUrlPart = "http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=";
        static string secondUrlPart = "&time=";
        static string thirdUrlPart = "&ir=";

        public class ProgressEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public int Percentage { get; set; }
            public string StateText { get; set; }
        }

        public event EventHandler<ProgressEventArgs> ProgressChanged;

        public void Init()
        {
            object obj = null;
            int index = 0;
            ExtractCountires();
            foreach (string cc in countriescodes)
            {
                // raise event here
                ProgressChanged?.Invoke(obj,new ProgressEventArgs{ Percentage = 100 * index / countriescodes.Count, StateText = cc });
                ExtractDateAndTime("http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=" + cc);
                index +=1;
            }
            ImagesLinks();
        }


        public void ExtractCountires()
        {
            try
            {
                htmltoextract = "http://sat24.com/en/?ir=true";//"http://sat24.com/en/";// + regions;
                client = new WebClient();
                client.DownloadFile(htmltoextract, @"c:\temp\sat24.html");
                client.Dispose();

                string tag1 = "<li><a href=\"/en/";
                string tag2 = "</a></li>";

                string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\sat24.html");
                s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(tag1));
                s = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(tag2) + tag2.ToCharArray().Length);
                s = s.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace(" ", "");

                string[] parts = s.Split(new string[] { tag1, tag2 }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


                string tag3 = "<li><ahref=\"/en/";

                for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 17)
                    {
                        //break;
                    }
                    string l = "";
                    if (parts[i].Contains(tag3))
                        l = parts[i].Replace(tag3, "");

                    string z1 = l.Substring(0, l.IndexOf('"'));
                    if (z1.Contains("</ul></li><liclass="))
                    {
                        z1 = z1.Replace("</ul></li><liclass=", "af");
                    }
                    countriescodes.Add(z1);
                    countriescodes.GroupBy(n => n).Any(c => c.Count() > 1);

                    string z2 = parts[i].Substring(parts[i].LastIndexOf('>') + 1);
                    if (z2.Contains("&amp;"))
                    {
                        z2 = z2.Replace("&amp;", " & ");
                    }
                    countriesnames.Add(z2);
                    countriesnames.GroupBy(n => n).Any(c => c.Count() > 1);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (countriescodes.Count == 0)
                {
                    countriescodes = new List<string>();
                    countriesnames = new List<string>();
                    DatesAndTimes = new List<string>();
                    imagesUrls = new List<string>();
                    Init();
                }
            }
        }

        public void ExtractDateAndTime(string baseAddress)
        {
            try
            {
                var wc = new WebClient();
                wc.BaseAddress = baseAddress;
                HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

                var temp = wc.DownloadData("/en");
                doc.Load(new MemoryStream(temp));

                var secTokenScript = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                    .Where(e =>
                           String.Compare(e.Name, "script", true) == 0 &&
                           String.Compare(e.ParentNode.Name, "div", true) == 0 &&
                           e.InnerText.Length > 0 &&
                           e.InnerText.Trim().StartsWith("var region")
                          ).FirstOrDefault().InnerText;
                var securityToken = secTokenScript;
                securityToken = securityToken.Substring(0, securityToken.IndexOf("arrayImageTimes.push"));
                securityToken = secTokenScript.Substring(securityToken.Length).Replace("arrayImageTimes.push('", "").Replace("')", "");
                var dates = securityToken.Trim().Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                var scriptDates = dates.Select(x => new ScriptDate { DateString = x });
                foreach (var date in scriptDates)
                {
                    DatesAndTimes.Add(date.DateString);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                countriescodes = new List<string>();
                countriesnames = new List<string>();
                DatesAndTimes = new List<string>();
                imagesUrls = new List<string>();
                this.Init();
            }
        }

        public class ScriptDate
        {
            public string DateString { get; set; }
            public int Year
            {
                get
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(this.DateString.Substring(0, 4));
                }
            }
            public int Month
            {
                get
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(this.DateString.Substring(4, 2));
                }
            }
            public int Day
            {
                get
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(this.DateString.Substring(6, 2));
                }
            }
            public int Hours
            {
                get
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(this.DateString.Substring(8, 2));
                }
            }
            public int Minutes
            {
                get
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(this.DateString.Substring(10, 2));
                }
            }
        }

        public void ImagesLinks()
        {
            int cnt = 0;
            foreach (string countryCode in countriescodes)
            {
                cnt++;
                for (; cnt < DatesAndTimes.Count(); cnt++)
                {
                    string imageUrl = firstUrlPart + countryCode + secondUrlPart + DatesAndTimes[cnt] + thirdUrlPart + "true";
                    imagesUrls.Add(imageUrl);
                    if (cnt % 10 == 0) break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In both cases where i'm using try and catch if it's getting to the catch i'm trying over again the whole operation by reseting the Lists and calling Init() again.

Then in form1

```
ExtractImages ei = new ExtractImages();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0;
            ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

events of backgroundworker

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return; // this will fall to the finally and close everything    
            }
            else
            {
                ei.ProgressChanged += (senders, eee) => backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(eee.Percentage, eee.StateText);
                ei.Init();
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            label7.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
            label8.Text = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
           if (e.Error == null)
            {
                ProgressBar1.Value = 100;
            }
           else
            {

            }
        }
```

Another thing not sure if it's a problem. When there is no a problem with the class i see in form1 in label7 all the codes running from the first to the last.
But the progressBar1.Value and label8 both are getting only to 97% so i need in the completed event to add the progressBar1.Value = 100; is that fine or there is a problem with the reporting calculation in the class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the 1st question:
Better catch the exception at client side and display the error msg, 'cause you probably need to control your program behavior accrodingly when sth went wrong. 
Consider this: if the DOM struct of the page changed, according to you code, your program probably throw expections, with each exception catching, client.DownloadFile is excuted for one time, if this happens, u will need to know what go wrong, and if u donot change ur code behavior, such hi-freq client.DownloadFile excution will cause the firewall of the website block ur ip for a while.
Add a timer at client side is a good idea i think.

For the 2nd one:
did u define how to handle RunWorkerCompleted event?

Comment: For the 2nd i didn't do much. Just checking in the completed event if there is no error and then set the value of the progressBar1 to 100: if (e.Error == null)
            {
                ProgressBar1.Value = 100;
            }